# How to transform images in PyTorch after downloading it?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, transfer-learning

Is there a way to transform images in pytorch after downloading it.

I have downloaded the Food101 dataset from torchvision.datasets.Food101, I got the ViT pretrained model from torchvision.models, and I got the transforms along with it. When downloading the dataset I used the following pieces of code:

```
from torchvision import datasets
from pathlib import Path

data_dir = Path("data")

train_data = datasets.Food101(root=data_dir,
                              split="train",
                              transform=train_transform,
                              download=True)

test_data = datasets.Food101(root=data_dir,
                             split="test",
                             transform=test_transform,
                             download=True)
```

Later, I want to try another model the ResNet151 model from torchvision.models, however since that has a different transform I want to know wether there is a way to transform the images without downloading the dataset again since it is a large dataset and seems inefficient? I do not want to use torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder() since the test and train data are all in one folder by default, and the current dataloaders were created automatically by pytorch.